# Python sort dictionary keys by letters and then numbers

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, numerical

Say I have a dictionary like this,

```
d = {"John1" : "blah blah", "John2" : "blah blah", "John11" : "blah blah", "Dave1" : "blah blah", "Dave2" : "blah blah", "Dave13" : "blah blah", "Dave23" : "blah blah"}
```

If want to be able to sort this so it is

```
d = {"Dave1" : "blah blah", "Dave2" : "blah blah", "Dave13" : "blah blah", "Dave23" : "blah blah", "John1" : "blah blah", "John2" : "blah blah", "John11" : "blah blah", }
```

Is there a way I can sort the keys of this dictionary alphabetically, then numerically?

Comment: It is not possible to sort a dict, only to get a representation of a dict that is sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that sorting the dictionary itself is really not what the data structure is intended for, but if you are looking for just a sorted list of the dictionary keys:

```
sorted(d.keys())
```

Where you can provide [sorted](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) with all sorts of good sorting functions to satisfy what ever burning desire you have. :)

Given how the keys are named a sorting function might look like...

```
def my_key(item):
    alpha = ''.join(i for i in item if i.isalpha())
    num = ''.join(i for i in item if i.isdigit())
    if num:
        return (alpha, int(num))
    return (alpha, 0)
```

and then:

```
sorted(d.keys(), key=my_key)
```

Comment: This does not sort by letters and then numbers. ['Dave1', 'Dave13', 'Dave2', 'Dave23',

Comment: @user2909250 as mentioned in his answer, you have to provide `sorted` with the sorting function you want.  The vanilla `sorted` function won't sort the way you want it to

Comment: Then what is the sorted function that I need?

Comment: How can I keep the dictionary keys intact with the values?